# PHP Dependency Injection - call injected object's method

Tags: php, class, dependency-injection

I'm learning about dependency injection in php and I think there's something I'm missing.

I created two classes, `Author` and `Article`:

```
class Author{
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;

    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName){
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName  = $lastName;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->firstName . " " . $this->lastName;
    }
}

class Article{
    private $author;
    private $content;

    public function __construct(Author $author, $content){
        $this->author  = $author;
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function getContent(){
        return $this->content;
    }
}
```

Then, on my index page, I instantiated my Article class and injected my Author class:

```
require "Classes.php";
$Article = new Article( new Author("Chris", "Schmitz"), "this is the content of my article");

print_r($Article);
```

Which prints out my object as expected:

```
Article Object ( [author:Article:private] => Author Object ( [firstName:Author:private] => Chris [lastName:Author:private] => Schmitz ) [content:Article:private] => this is the content of my article )
```

This all makes sense, but when I go to call the public method `getName()` from my `Author` class I get an error:

```
echo $Article->author->getName();
// produces php error: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access private property Article::$author
```

If I'm injecting one object into the other, shouldn't I be able to access the injected object's public methods? Am I misunderstanding how the injection is expected to work? Did I set it up wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$author` is a `private` property of `Article`, meaning you can only access it from methods inside that class.

Although the `getName()` method is indeed `public`, all parts of the `->` chain have to be visible from the context in which you're using them - unfortunately `author` isn't.

As suggested by Halim, the cleanest way to address the error is to create a `public` getter method for the `author` property in your `Article` class:

```
public function getAuthor() {
    return $this->author;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that would break the encapsulation principle. Adding a simple `getAuthor()` method would be more appreciable and preserve the encapsulation of the members in the class.

Comment: @HalimQarroum Very true.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton: Ah, *facepalm*. If it was a snake it would have bit me in the face. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @HalimQarroum, just to make sure I understand, if I were to add a `getAuthor()` method to the `Article` class, would it just be a method that returned the call to the injected class's `getAuthor()` method

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz No; it would return the injected object itself - otherwise you couple `Article` to `Author`. Not to mention `Author` doesn't have a `getAuthor()` method...